# Learning Kotlin and stuck with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I am learning Kotlin and all was going well until it stopped working, the only thing I changed were the references.
I've tried to adjust the "this" parameter and it has not worked, 
Here is my code:

```
    package com.example.myweatherapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class ForecastActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forecast)



         var retriever = WeatherRetriever()

            val callback = object : Callback<Weather> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Weather>?, t: Throwable) {
                println("It failed")
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<Weather>?, response: Response<Weather>?) {
                    println("It wORKED")

                    println(response?.body()?.main)

                    title = response?.body()?.name

                    var forecasts = response?.body()?.main

                    var castListView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.forecastListView)

                    var adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@ForecastActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forecasts)

                    castListView.adapter=adapter
                }

            }
            retriever.getForecast(callback)
        }

        }
```

I am getting the following error: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:"
Any help for a newbie?
Thanks a lot!

Edit: Here is the weather class

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface weatherAPI{
    @GET("weather?id=3621224&units=metric&appid=ff2563aab36fc89bc7a3c4fe58dd7f3e")
    fun getForecast() : Call<Weather>
}

class Weather(val main: WeatherForecast, val name: String )
class WeatherForecast (val main: List<main>)
class main (val temp: String, val feels_like: String, val temp_min: String, val temp_max: String)


class WeatherRetriever {
    val service : weatherAPI

    init {
    val retrofit=    Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    service = retrofit.create(weatherAPI::class.java)
    }
    fun getForecast(callback : Callback<Weather>){
        val call = service.getForecast()
        call.enqueue(callback)

    }

}
```

Comment: Try using val instead var wherever you can. You are using wrong function signature. Please post the full stacktrace of your error.

Comment: @SusheelKaram from what OP has posted it's clear there will be no stacktrace as it won't be compile, OP said they are getting an error regarding signatures, which means it won't compile.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks for correcting (Not sure if it "stack trace" is right word). But what I meant is to post him full error message. As it could possible show more info about where it went wrong.

Comment: could you post your `Weather` class?

Comment: Added the class

Comment: @SusheelKaram This is the error message I get: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: Array<(out) (???..???)>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(p0: Context, p1: Int, p2: (Mutable)List<(???..???)>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter